# Readability Scores for Multiple Text Files in R

Tags: r, text, readability, fog

I am very new to R. I would be very thankful if you could share a code to help me with the following.

I want to calculate readability scores (such as: **FOG Index**, **SMOG Index**, **Flesch–Kincaid Score** etc.) using R for several independent text files (.txt) present in a folder.

I also want one output file (.csv) which includes readability scores of the text files.

Many thanks in advance.

Warm Regards,
Farhan

Comment: Hi Farhan, I think this is too general for SO, you might have better luck trying to find blogs/training videos of someone having done this type of analysis. As I see it, there are 3 parts here: loading in multiple files - for that you will find many resources, doing the actual analysis (readability scores) - this I am not familiar with, but there might be R packages that you can search for, and lastly, compelling the results and writing out the csv - I'd say there you will also find many resources on how to do that.

Comment: These readability scores (among others) are implemented in the `koRpus` package (see [its vignette](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/koRpus/doc/koRpus_vignette.html) for details)